# HtmlPolicyBuilder href is not coming in <u >tag after using PolicyFactory.sanitize in java code

Tags: java, xss, owasp, cross-site, html-sanitizing

```
<u href="javascript:toggleTable('*****')" onMouseOver="this.style.color='red'" onMouseOut="this.style.color='#000000'">*****</u>
```

Above element under th tag after sanitising href attribute is not coming as shown below :

```
<u onmouseover="this.style.color='red'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'">*****</u>
```

Below is the code snippet which I'm trying to allow href attribute under u element :

```
PolicyFactory html = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
.allowElements("u")
.allowAttributes("href", "onMouseOver", "onMouseOut").onElements("u")
.allowTextIn("u")
.allowCommonBlockElements()
.allowCommonInlineFormattingElements()
.allowStandardUrlProtocols()
.allowUrlProtocols("href")
.allowStyling()
.requireRelNofollowOnLinks()
.allowAttributes("href").globally()
.toFactory();
```

same issue I'm facing with table and tr element as well. Style attribute is not coming under table and tr element also.

Any suggestion/help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` attribute is being removed because it doesn't have an allowed protocol. If `.allowUrlProtocols("href")` is changed to `.allowUrlProtocols("javascript")` then it would be allowed.

Allowing `javascript` URLs, or `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` attributes will allow scripts to be executed though and be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Instead, you can change the design. Mouse-over styling doesn't need JavaScript. It can be done the CSS `:hover` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

As answer above adding `javascript`  in `.allowUrlProtocols("javascript")` will allow to pass, but where as you will still get UTF encoded `"("` & `")"` in `javascript:toggleTable('*****')` as `"("` & `")"` comes into special character.

your output will look like `javascript:toggleTable0028'*****'0029`

To make it work you will have to replace it with string function replace.

```
sanitizer.sanitize(HTML).replace("0028", "(").replace("0029",")");
```